# How to use Wordpress contant form 7 and fancy box to display particular section when on_sent_ok or fancybox close

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, fancybox, contact-form-7

I have a problem with wp contact form 7 and fancy box. I need to show a hidden content after the form is submitted. When my form is submitted i couldn't able to display that code.

```
 <div class="col-md-offset-8 col-md-4 text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary show" data-fancybox="modal" data-src="#modal" href="javascript:;">View The Technical Specification </a></div>
```

//Fancybox Modal

```
<section>
    <div id="modal" style="display: none; padding: 50px 5vw; max-width: 800px;text-align: center;">
                <h3>Provide the details</h3>
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="816" title="Download From"]'); ?>

    </div>
    </section>
```

once this form is submitted i want to display something like this

```
<div id="show" > 
    ....................
         .............
    .......................
</div>
```

Here is the Script i tried

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
          afterClose: function () {
           $('#show').fadeIn(); // or .show()
          })
        });
```

i couldn't display the particular section..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you did not use correct selector and therefore your custom options were not applied. It should be like this:

```
$('[data-fancybox="modal"]').fancybox({
  afterClose: function () {
    $('#show').show()
  }
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YrYqzy

Comment: Good work! it working only when i close my self, i need it when the form submitted the fancybox will close that moment  `#show` should work.

Comment: But where is the problem? Just close fancybox when the form is submitted. I have updated the demo.

Comment: when the form is submitted it close fancybox the url change to `http://demo.com/#modal` to `http://demo.com/#wpc7-fm` so the fancybox will disappear, once again i want get into fancy box and close. then it show, either form should stay or must close auto then show hidden content.

Answer (score 0):

When we submit the contact form 7 it will redirect from url `http://demo.com/` to `http://demo.com/#wpc7-fm.`Here if fancybox form `#modal` is active then the url will change `http://demo.com/#modal`. Once the form submitted the url will replace to `http://demo.com/#wpc7-fm` in that case our fancybox will disappears due to the url `#modal` replaced with `#wpc7`.`
Example:-

```
$('[data-fancybox="modal"]').fancybox({
afterClose: function () {
$('#show').show()
}
});
```

Above code just trigger `$('#show').show()`

But after form submission above code will become inactive in the case.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
if ( location.hash != 0 && location.hash == '#wpcf7-fm' ){

    $('#show').show();

    }


});
```

This Location hash can activate the hidden content.